Как работать с нужными модулями в Jupyter Notebook? Python не видит модуль при обращении через `import` в браузере
Я хочу разобратьcя с кодом, написанным на Python, и переработать его для Matlab. Есть два файла - файл скрипта и файл с набором необходимых функций (оба файла есть как в формате .py, так и в .ipynb), к которым скрипт должен обращаться во время выполнения.
Я загрузил в рабочее пространство Jupyter оба файла. Сначала я попытался просто запустить скрипт целиком и посмотреть, что получится.
Первую ошибку с cm.spectral я исправил, заменив этот кусок кода на cm.Spectral.
А вот со следующей ошибкой я пока не разобрался. Выглядит она вот так:

Скрипт и набор функций находятся в одном рабочем пространстве. Как в таком случае поступать, когда нет возможности загрузить модуль в рабочее пространство?

Никакие GUI не будут работать в браузере. Tkinter тоже не будет работать. Там практически это и написано.

@CrazyElf тогда попробую убрать и посмотреть, что получится.

Если у вас там весь интерфейс на Tkinter написан, то всё придётся переписывать "вручную". Ну или весь выкидывать. В браузере всё по-другому.

@CrazyElf Для меня главное — посмотреть, что там вообще считается и визуализировать результаты с помощью инструментов Python, доступных в браузере. Использование TTinker не принципиально.
